# Error deploying Service Fabric application - Cannot index into a null array

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have configured a deployment to a Service Fabric application using Visual Studio Team Services (**hosted agent**). Everything was working as expected until very recently. Now deployments are failing with the following error message:

> Cannot index into a null array.

Task is configured as follows:

[image]

This is the full log of the deployment task:

```
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4033826Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Service Fabric Application
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z ==============================================================================
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z Task         : Service Fabric Application Deployment
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z Description  : Deploy a Service Fabric application to a cluster.
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z Version      : 1.3.3
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4113825Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=820528)
2017-02-13T13:23:25.4123824Z ==============================================================================
2017-02-13T13:23:28.3707902Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.7.1 commit f990f8d8df6197b1cfcec01031ba014ad4905681
2017-02-13T13:23:28.7247919Z ##[debug]Entering D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\deploy.ps1.
2017-02-13T13:23:28.7397904Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\task.json
2017-02-13T13:23:28.8877911Z ##[debug]Loaded 49 strings.
2017-02-13T13:23:28.8977907Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2017-02-13T13:23:28.8987909Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2017-02-13T13:23:29.0617895Z ##[debug]Loaded 49 strings.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.1177896Z ##[debug]INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILEPATH: 'D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.1805007Z Searching for path: D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml
2017-02-13T13:23:29.2145006Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.2305008Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.2895008Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.2944996Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.3034992Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2017-02-13T13:23:29.3104997Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.3135007Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.3405018Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.5979986Z ##[debug]Path: D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml
2017-02-13T13:23:29.6040007Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.6079982Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2017-02-13T13:23:29.6109978Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.6329988Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.6350041Z Found path: D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\ServiceFabric\Config\PublishProfiles\Cloud.qa.xml
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7000090Z ##[debug]INPUT_APPLICATIONPACKAGEPATH: 'D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7010019Z Searching for path: D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7049996Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7079987Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7100038Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'True'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7140043Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7169997Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7200023Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7230026Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'False'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7250041Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'True'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.7720050Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z ##[debug]Path: D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z ##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9969997Z Found path: D:\a\r1\a\publish\Release
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9979996Z ##[debug]INPUT_SERVICECONNECTIONNAME: '307f16ba-c7b0-44be-9998-050e6075a9b6'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9979996Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_URL_307f16ba-c7b0-44be-9998-050e6075a9b6: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.azure.com:19000/'
2017-02-13T13:23:29.9979996Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_AUTH_xxxxxxxxxxxx: '********'
2017-02-13T13:23:30.0010004Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_DATA_xxxxxxxxxxxx: '{}'
2017-02-13T13:23:30.0079998Z ##[debug]INPUT_COPYPACKAGETIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.0169999Z ##[debug]INPUT_REGISTERPACKAGETIMEOUTSEC (empty)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.0209986Z ##[debug]INPUT_COMPRESSPACKAGE: 'true'
2017-02-13T13:23:30.1139975Z ##[warning]Your deploy task has been upgraded to a new version with possible breaking changes. The Cluster Endpoint defined in your service endpoint was previously ignored, but will now override the value in the publish profile. Verify the endpoint is correct and prefixed with 'https://'. In addition, a Server Certificate Thumbprint field has been added to the service endpoint and will also override the publish profile value. Your service endpoint may not have been updated to allow specifying the Server Certificate Thumbprint, in which case we will still use the value from the publish profile and you should try again soon.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.1139975Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]Your deploy task has been upgraded to a new version with possible breaking changes. The Cluster Endpoint defined in your service endpoint was previously ignored, but will now override the value in the publish profile. Verify the endpoint is correct and prefixed with 'https://'. In addition, a Server Certificate Thumbprint field has been added to the service endpoint and will also override the publish profile value. Your service endpoint may not have been updated to allow specifying the Server Certificate Thumbprint, in which case we will still use the value from the publish profile and you should try again soon.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.2456671Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\deploy.ps1.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.2646567Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.2696555Z ##[debug]Error record:
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3756887Z ##[debug]D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\deploy.ps1 : Cannot index into a null array.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3766890Z ##[debug]At line:1 char:1
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3786885Z ##[debug]+ . 'D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c ...
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3806878Z ##[debug]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3816887Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [deploy.ps1], RuntimeException
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3836876Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray,deploy.ps1
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3846887Z ##[debug] 
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3876887Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3926870Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.3\deploy.ps1: line 57
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3946887Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3966873Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3976888Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2017-02-13T13:23:30.3996872Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4026873Z ##[debug]Exception:
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4166884Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4186886Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4206873Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4216885Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4236885Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4256882Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4266885Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4286885Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4306872Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4316888Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4639786Z ##[error]Cannot index into a null array.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4639786Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Cannot index into a null array.
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4666547Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2017-02-13T13:23:30.4886539Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
```

BTW I've noticed that the hosted agents were updated recently (2/7/2017), I'm wondering if that could be related to this issue?

Comment: Based on my test to deploy Service Fabric Application via VSTS build (hosted agent) with a new Service Fabric cluster on Azure (no Authentication), it works fine. What's the result if you deploy it to azure on your local machine? On the other hand, there is a warning, do you change something?

Comment: I asked one of the developers that were using the application - deploying from his local machine was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened but I was able to fix the problem.

I have deleted the Azure Service Fabric endpoint and created a new one (Certificate Based), with the correct Thumbprint, Client Certificate, Password etc.